nvm command not found after installation via elevated PowerShell

Installed nvm for Windows (version 1.1.12) by running nvm-setup.exe in PowerShell with elevated privileges.
Installation wizard completed successfully without errors.
Started a new PowerShell session as the privileged user.
Attempted to execute nvm, which resulted in the error:
"ObjectNotFound: (nvm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException"
Checked environment variables using:

[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('NVM_HOME')
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH')


note: installing via eleated cmd is doing the job
The nvm command should be available in the system's PATH and work correctly when executed
